# Best way to store text with very differernt length in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, column-types

I want to store a text to SQL Server. My text has very different lengths (1-10000 characters length). I want to store text with minimum size tenure in database.

My question: what do I have to select as the column type?

And when we select a type for a column like a `varchar(100)` when we add row with value null for the column, does the database size increase?

For example, I have table like this:

```
id    txt(Varchar(100))     
---  -----
1     some text     
2     null
```

when I add a row with a null value for txt column, does the database size increase?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`varchar` is the only option here. it is stored by database efficiently and takes as much as space needed (+overhead).
By that mean, if you'r data is 100 character it will use less storage than when your data is 1000 character.
This is a good book to read about it: "Microsoft SQL Server 2008 Internals"

Comment: thanks for your attention but if when we create a varchar(1000) column  and we store data with 100 char it takes less space than we store row with 1000 char, so why we should select column size?

Comment: The column size is the maximum size you can store in the column.

Comment: yes! but why we should select that if SQL automatically managing column sizes. I mean we select max all column sizes if when  data is 100 character it will use less storage than when data is 1000 character

Comment: Sql server should know the maximum size of a record in advance. Because max row size in sql is about 8k. more data types are known on size and you need to specify size so that sql server can guarantee your data insert will not fail.